# Is there a way to create a work "handoff" flow in SharePoint? Where users complete a task and sends it to other users to complete additional tasks?

Tags: sharepoint

All,

I'm new to SharePoint, and I was wondering if there was a way to have a group of users complete a task (perhaps a form that needs answered), and then have that form, or the answers given in that form, be sent to another group of users to look into and follow-up on? Perhaps it could be moved to a specific folder?

Google hasn't turned up much of anything in the way of clear answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism you are mentioning is like a SharePoint Approval workflow or an approval flow.

Just like teylyn said, you can choose SharePoint Designer workflow or Power automate depends on the version of SharePoint you are using.

[How to determine the SharePoint version I am using](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f).

And SharePoint has its own [built-in approval workflow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/all-about-approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742) template for directly use. It is a bit old but easy to configure and ready to be used.

An example for SharePoint designer 2013 platform approval workflow [here](https://sharepointdiv.wordpress.com/2019/02/12/sharepoint-2013-2016-approval-workflow-with-3-dynamically-determined-approves-using-sharepoint-designer/).

[2010 Platform approval workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NcqLRNN4-Q)

One thing just for your notice, there are two different types of workflows, 2010 platform workflow and 2013 platform workflow. You can create a 2010 platform as long as you installed SharePoint Designer. However it is needed to install and configure workflow manager to use 2013 platform workflow.

Flow tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals).

Hope to be any help.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, you can use Power Automate to create business logic workflows, using fields in a SharePoint list that store the current status of a task and information like next reviewer, etc. The Power Automate flow can be either triggered by a button in the form (in which case you would want to design the form with PowerApps) or whenever the item in the SharePoint list is modified.

In SharePoint on premises you can create SharePoint Designer workflows to achieve the same thing.